# Type 'string | boolean | null' is not assignable to type 'boolean'. Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'boolean'

Tags: typescript

What's wrong with this code?

```
isAuthenticated(): boolean
  {
    var token = localStorage.getItem(ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY);
    return token && !this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(token);
  }
```

Error:

```
Type 'string | boolean | null' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
   Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
```

Comment: What is unclear from the error message?

Comment: Please keep in mind that operator `&&` does not return `boolean` by the default.  See simple example `const result = 'hello' && 42 // 42`. In order to fix your code  try `return Boolean(token && !this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(token))`

Comment: If `token` is `null` or `""` then you `null` or `""` respectively. You can try to change to `return !!token && ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to return boolean, you need to cast these variables to a boolean value.
For example:

```
isAuthenticated(): boolean
  {
    var token = localStorage.getItem(ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY);
    return !!token && !!this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(token);
  }
```